# Get Trigger's name or error message in DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have several `triggers` in the database and based on some conditions they might throw an error and `rollback transaction`.

The problem is that in the `catch` block I'll receive a `DbUpdateException` that doesn't contain any information about the cause of the error, and inner exceptions don't have any meaningful error message neither.

How can I get the error message or trigger's name, when I'm using `Entity Framework`? I need to do that to be able to show friendly messages to the user.

The second inner exception is a `SqlException`, yet casting it to a `SqlException` doesn't help since the `Procedure` is an empty string.

```
(e?.InnerException?.InnerException as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException).Procedure
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the trigger name, you'll need to include that in the error message.  Below is a boilerplate code example.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN TRY
    --do something;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2000) = 
        'Error occurred in trigger ' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) + ':' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1);
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I can't even get the error message. Either will do, I just want to know what has happened.

Answer (score 0):

This reply assumes you are using MSSQL Server...if not ignore...

IN your SQL code change RAISERROR to:
THROW 50000, <@YourErrormsg>, 16 ;

Notes on SQL code:

1. if you are not useing semicolons after your statements, THROWS needs one in front of it, else it generates error (server won't let you update trigger).
2. If you want to rollback entire trans (say code is in trigger) before THROW do: SET XACT_ABORT ON. Unlike RAISERROR, THROWS uses XACT_ABORT to detirmine to rollback or not (thus can be used for FYI messages as well if SET XACT_ABORT OFF).
3. Error# needs to be => 50000. Use a specific number if you are using numbers have additional meaning (you could have C# enum on client side in a switch, I just set to 50001 for all business errors in trigger as I just needed message).

In your C# code use try catch with a catch of:

catch (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
At first I had just (SqlException ex), but that resolved to: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, which will NOT have your message.
Use full: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException for your catch.

ex.Messsage will have your custom set message in your sql code.
ex.Prodecure will have the name of the database object that throws it (it my case it was a trigger as well, so that's where to look)

This took me a while to figure out, especially the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException **vs**
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException